# Doctrine LazyLoad

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I try to use lazy load on my project. But it didn work. Here is my relation definition:

`/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\TripBundle\Entity\TripRespond", mappedBy="trip", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $responds;`

But when I var_dump my trip it returns with all related entities. What I am doing wrong?

Fetching of trips:

```
        $trips = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeTripBundle:Trip')->searchByPoints($startPoint, $endPoint);
        var_dump($trips);die;
```

Comment: You need to post how you fetched your "trip" object

Comment: I believe var_dump calls the getter functions and thus the fields will be populated upon access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine by default lazy load the object(s) unless any of the method is called.
When the object(s) were lazy loaded it creates a proxy class with following properties and values:

```
["__IS_PROXY__"] => bool(true)
["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"] => bool(false)
```

Try to dump your object with `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($trips);` and see if such properties/values exist.